# Set JSON Data to Java Model and Iterate Over Jsp

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, jackson, jackson-databind

i am new to working with Api in java. Can Any One Help To Implement This in Better Way. I Have A JSON OBJECT. like..

```
{
  "firstState": {
    "district": {
      "first": {
        "polulation": 100000,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      },
      "second": {
        "polulation": 326565,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "secondState": {
    "district": {
      "first": {
        "polulation": 70000,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      },
      "second": {
        "polulation": 15245,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to map all this value in model so that i can show those values in jsp. my class for the that object is.

```
public class States {

    @JsonProperty("firstState")
    private Districts kerala;

    @JsonProperty("secondState")
    private Districts kerala;
getter settter....
}


class Districts {
    @JsonProperty("district")
    private Object districts;
getter settter....
    }
```

my controller code is:

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(result);
            States states = objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, States.class);
```

can any one guide me how should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your JSON mapping is a little off. See below for correction.

```
public class States {
    @JsonProperty("firstState")
    private Districts kerala1;

    @JsonProperty("secondState")
    private Districts kerala2;

    // getter, setter
}

public class Districts {
    @JsonProperty
    private District district;

    // getter, setter
}

public class District {
    @JsonProperty
    private DistrictInfo first;

    @JsonProperty
    private DistrictInfo second;
    // getter, setter
}

public class DistrictInfo {
    @JsonProperty
    private long polulation;

    @JsonProperty
    private String lastupdatedtime;

    @JsonProperty
    private Delta delta;

    // getter, setter
}

public class Delta {
    @JsonProperty
    private long confirmed;

    // getter, setter
}
```

In your controller, you shouldn't need to use the `ObjectMapper` directly as Spring abstracts this for you as part of the `RestTemplate` given it has the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` as an available message converter (which Spring Boot does for you). See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-resttemplate for more information on `RestTemplate` usage.

```
@GetMapping
public String getStates(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("states", restTemplate.getForObject(url, States.class));
    return "path/to/statesJsp"
}
```

In your JSP, use the dot notation to traverse your fields of `States`.

```
<h1>Kerala First District Population</h1>
<p>${state.kerala1.district.first.polulation}</p>
```

Note, been a long while since I've used JSPs but in theory that should do it.